# Python: Generate dictionary from pandas dataframe with rows as keys and columns as values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     Curricula Course1 Course2 Course3 ... CourseN
0       q1      c1        c2     NaN        NaN
1       q2      c14       c21    c1         Nan
2       q3      c2        c14    NaN        Nan
...
M       qm      c7        c9     c21
```

Where the number of Courses per Curricula is different.

What I need is a dictionary from this dataframe looking like this:

```
{'q1': 'c1', 'q1': 'c2', 'q2': 'c14', 'q2': 'c21', 'q2: 'c1' ... }
```

Where the row names are my keys and for each row, the dictionary is filled with all the 'Curricula': 'Course' information that is given, excluding 'NaN' values.

What i tried so far was set the index to the 'Curricula' column, transposing the dataframe and using the to_dict('records') methods but this resulted in the following output:

in:

```
df.set_index('Curricula')
df_transposed = df.transpose()
Dic = df_transposed.to_dict('records')
```

out:

```
[{0: 'q1', 1: 'q2', 2: 'q3', ... }, {0: 'c1', 1: 'c14', 2: 'c2' ...} ... {0: NaN, 1: 'c1', 2: 'Nan']
```

So here the columns integer values are used as keys instead of my wanted 'Curricula' column values and additionally, the NaN values are not excluded.

Anyone an idea how to fix that?

Best regards,
Jan

Comment: How do you expect to have duplicate keys in your dictionary? that's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Curricula': {0: 'q1', 1: 'q2', 2: 'q3'},
 'Course1': {0: 'c1', 1: 'c14', 2: 'c2'},
 'Course2': {0: 'c2', 1: 'c21', 2: 'c14'},
 'Course3': {0: np.nan, 1: 'c1', 2: np.nan}})

print(df)

  Curricula Course1 Course2 Course3
0        q1      c1      c2     NaN
1        q2     c14     c21      c1
2        q3      c2     c14     NaN
```

---

You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary, however you can use `agg` along with `set_index` and `stack` to create a list for each unique key:

```
df.set_index('Curricula').stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list).to_dict()
```

```
{'q1': ['c1', 'c2'], 'q2': ['c14', 'c21', 'c1'], 'q3': ['c2', 'c14']}
```

Comment: Total newbie = Totally forgot about duplicate keys... xD
I will need some time to figure out how to work around my duplicate keys problem. Thank you very much for your answer @user3483203 ! I will go forward working with your answer :)

Comment: @JanB also, I should have mentioned, in your code when you call `set_index`, it doesn't do anything because `set_index` is not in place by default.  You can call `df.set_index('foo', inplace=True)`, but your result is being lost.